# IEnumerable.GetEnumerator throws InvalidCastException -> Why do I not get an compile time error?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, exception, ienumerable

I found a very confusing issue and I Hope you can help me understanding this issue.
My goal was to have struct which i can easly iterate over for readability purposes. 
Unfortunatly I recieved and InvalidCastException and I do not understandt why this happend. I believe the compiler should not have been able to compile it:

**Originally**

I expected it to work out of the box because  I let the interface be implemented over a field of that struct with the help of Reshaper but I recieved a InvalidCastException when running my unittests(luckly there and not in production) trying to iterate over my field.

As I said the problem occured while iterating which means the GetEnumerator() method throws the InvalidCastException. What did I using as underlaying object which I want to iterate over? It is an ConcurrentDictionary (see code example) I found several Questions regarding the IEnumerable Interface.

And as far as i can tell regarding the implemention of that interface have done nothing wrong which is at least visibly obvious.

- [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() and IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442192/ienumerable-getenumerator-and-ienumerablet-getenumerator)
- [Implementing IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() in a wrapper dictionary class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584106/implementing-ienumerable-getenumerator-in-a-wrapper-dictionary-class)
- [How would you implement the IEnumerator interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967/how-would-you-implement-the-ienumerator-interface)

```
public struct test : IEnumerable<(int, string)>
{
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string,(int,string)> dictionary ;

        public IEnumerator<(int, string)> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<(int,string)>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<(int,string)>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }
}
```

My understanding was that ConcurrentDictionary Implements IEnumerable and therefore i should be able to simply forward these method calls. At First I thought it might has something todo with  invariant/covariant type parameter

- [How do i convert a class (which is derived from a generic "base" class) to that generic "base" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108922/how-do-i-convert-a-class-which-is-derived-from-a-generic-base-class-to-that)
- [Casting generic class type to its base class fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206089/casting-generic-class-type-to-its-base-class-fails)

But this does not explain that behaviour to me. So I checked microsofts docu: [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) and discovered *my idiocy:* **I wanted to Iterate over my Values not the pair of keys and values.**

---

**After a lot of thoughts**

I cannot get my head around why i am getting an error at Runtime if the types apparently do work out fine at compile time. It should **NOT** compile in the first place. What am i missing?

I have somekind of idea why [if I look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170971/1559338) but were speaking about a cast of an IEnumerable with 1 generic type argument vs 2 generic type arguments. Is this difference not enough? Shouldn't this be detectable from the compiler?

Comment: Typo? `return ((IEnumerable<(int,string)>)dictionary.Values).GetEnumerator();` or actually `return dictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, dictionary values collection inherits `IEnumerable<(int, string)>` type

Comment: all generic types are constructed and runtime, not at compile time. So the incorrect cast fails in runtime, it's a main reason, IMO